# Ruby script to send image with net/http and POST request

Tags: ruby, post, net-http

On a ruby project I am trying to send a image to a server listening to POSTS requests. I would like to avoid using extra necessary gems. I am using ruby 1.9.3 and net/http
Multiport is not supported by the server and the following code:

```
require 'net/http'  
require "uri"

image = File.open(image.path, 'r')

url = URI("http://someserver/#{image_name}")
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
headers = {"X-ClientId" => client_id, "X-ClientSecret" => client_secret, "Content-Type" => "image/jpeg"}
response, body = req.post(url.path, image, headers)
```

crashes with the following error message:

```
http.rb:1932:in `send_request_with_body': undefined method `bytesize' for #<File:0x007ffdcd335270> (NoMethodError)
```

While the following succeed in bash:

```
curl -i -X POST --data-binary @./output.jpg -H 'X-ClientId: ##..##' -H 'X-ClientSecret: ##..##' http:/someserver/output.jpg
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the file into a string, don't try and send the File instance. `post(url.path, image.read, headers)` better yet dont open a file and not close it. `image = File.read('image_path.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

Go through this for ruby script- http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

**OR**
And for rails you can use 'httmultiparty'.
Go through this - https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty

Here is example you can do -

In your controller method just add -

```
class SomeController <  ApplicationController
   def send_file
       response = Foo.post('/', :query => {
                  :file => File.new('abc.txt') 
       })
       # here Foo is class_name which is present in model/foo.rb
       response.code # it give response code success or failure.
   end
end
```

In model just make any file, let foo.rb and add following code -

```
require 'httmultiparty'
class Foo
   include HTTMultiParty
   base_uri 'my/path' #url where to send file 
end
```

You will get file on your path by just doing params[:file] . I think this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am not using Rails and server doesn't support multipart uploads.